# Excel VBA - Overflow error on Range select

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an error when I try to select cells from a sheet:

```
  Dim ABHdataPath As String
  Dim ABHdataFile As Excel.Workbook

  ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Activate ' make sure program starts from correct sheet
        ColumnName = ColumnLetter(ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)
        ABHbooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:" & ColumnName & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row).Value
```

When running above line, I get this error:

[image]

It doesn't give me any option to debug the code, so I find it hard to locate the error.

**EDIT**
I have been able to debug my code, this is where it ends:

```
ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:" & ColumnName & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row).Value
```

**Debug:**

> ABHBooked = Empty
>
> Rows.Count = 1048576
>
> xlUp = -4162
>
> ColumnName = CD

Comment: If you run step by step with F8 on which line do you get the error? Do you have something in your code declared as `Integer`? If yes, declare it as `Long`.

Comment: @Vityata please see my updated question. It is already defined as "Long"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not that my variable wasn't stored as `long`, but rather the format of my selection.

This fixed the issue:

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "General”
```

Answer (score 0):

The function gives error whenever the ColumnNumber is less than 1. Thus, introduce a small check and it should work:

```
Function ColumnLetter(ColumnNumber As Long) As String
    Dim n As Long
    Dim c As Byte
    Dim s As String

    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then
        ColumnLetter = "NAN"
        Exit Function
    End If

    n = ColumnNumber
    Do
        c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)
        s = Chr(c + 65) & s
        n = (n - c) \ 26
    Loop While n > 0
    ColumnLetter = s

End Function
```

Comment: Hi again! Sorry, I just checked. Now I am able to debug, and this is where it ends:
 `ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:" & ColumnName & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row).Value`

Comment: @oliverbj - is `ABHBooked` an `Integer`?

Comment: just updated my question. ABHBooked is defined in another function as variant: `Public ABHBooked As Variant`

Comment: @oliverbj - have you tried to copy and paste my function to your code?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it still gives me "oveflow". I have updated my OP to include the debug, where the codes "breaks"

Comment: @oliverbj - what is the value of `ColumnName`?

Comment: ColumnName = `"CD"`

Comment: @oliverbj - try to hard code it and see what happens - `ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:CD10")`

Comment: Should I also include the `Cells(Rows.Count...` in this ?

Comment: @oliverbj - nope, just try the hard-coded values. If it works, try to include the stuff.

Comment: When I just use `ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:CD10")` it runs fine. **NO** Overflow error

Comment: @oliverbj - cool. Then change `CD10` to the real row number. Check what exactly `Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` is returning, hardcode it and try again.

Comment: So first like this? `ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:CD5522")`? (CD5522 is the last row).

Comment: @oliverbj - yes.

Comment: If I hardcode `.Range(B5:CD5522)` it gives me `Overflow` error again

Comment: @oliverbj - cool. Now write `Dim ABHBooked2 as Variant` on the top of the sub and use it like this - `ABHBooked2 = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:CD5522")`

Comment: @oliverbj - What are the values inside `B5:CD5522`?

Comment: A lot of cells with dates, and the rest just text. The dates are formatted as custom: `dd-mm-yy hh:mm`

Comment: @oliverbj - if you try it on a new excel, only this `ABHBooked = ABHdataFile.Sheets("Booked").Range("B5:CD5522")` would it work?

Comment: No unfortunately not. However if I set `Range("B5:CD100")` it gives me error. As soon as I change it to `CD5522` it gives me the error

Comment: @oliverbj - really, if you try in a completely new Excel file, it does not work again?